What is the name of this generalization of the Zappa-Szép product?
Semidirect product is a generalization of direct product in that it does not require both factors to be normal subgroups. Zappa-Szép product is a generalization of semidirect product in that it does not require either factor to be a normal subgroup. What is the name of the generalization of Zappa-Szép product so that we allow one of the factors to be a subset only, not forming a subgroup (because it isn't closed under multiplication)?
The definition of the (internal) Zappa-Szép product is this:

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$, and let $H$ and $K$
be subgroups of $G$. The following statements are equivalent:

$G$ = $HK$ and $H\cap K = \{e\}$
For each $g$ in $G$, there exists a unique $h$ in $H$ and a unique $k$ in $K$ such that $g = hk$.   If either (and hence both) of these
statements hold, then $G$ is said to be an internal Zappa–Szép
product of $H$ and $K$.


Here is an example of the above-mentioned "generalized Zappa-Szép product":
It's known that every element of the restricted Lorentz group (the identity component of the Lorentz group) can be written uniquely as the product of a rotation and a boost, and the only common element of the boosts and the rotations is the identity, so this looks like the Zappa-Szép product, except boosts don't form a group. What more simple examples can be given of this kind of "generalized Zappa-Szép product", and what is its "official" name?

Hint: You can represent +(3,1)
as a traditional ZS product = using the stabilizer of a timelike vector as  and a suitable 3-dimensional subgroup  of the stabilizer of a light-like line. Try to figure out which  to take.

Isn't this just a subgroup together with an associated (left or right) transversal?
